# Maven AntRun plugin include root folder on tar

Tags: maven, tar

on my project I need to create a tar with the full content of a folder.
I do it with the maven antRun plugin.
My problems is that the main root isn't in to the tar.
How to insert the folder?

Es.
I have

```
Target
---temp
---Example
------aaa.png
------bbbb.png
------rsc
---------ccc.png
```

Im my file.tar.gz I Have

```
aaa.png
bbbb.png
rsc
---ccc.png
```

I wanna

```
---Example
------aaa.png
------bbbb.png
------rsc
---------ccc.png
```

Code to create the tar

```
   <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>tar batch</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <target name="tar.gz folder">
                                    <echo message="Starting to compress with tar.gz ${main.builddir}${file.separator}${tar.name.batch} in ${main.builddir}${file.separator}${tar.name.batch}.tar.gz " />
                                    <tar destfile="${main.builddir}${file.separator}${tar.name.batch}.tar" basedir="${main.builddir}${file.separator}${tar.name.batch}" />
                                    <gzip destfile="${project.build.directory}${file.separator}${tar.name.batch}.tar.gz" src="${main.builddir}${file.separator}${tar.name.batch}.tar" />
                                </target>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not the cleanest solution, but i solved adding another sub folder, 
so when I generate the jar, i put it in executable/executable, and after i make the tar.gz of the first executable's folder.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) instead of maven-antrun-plugin. You need a configuration in your pom file like this:

```xml
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>create-archives</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <descriptors>
                <descriptor>src/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
              </descriptors>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Furthermore you need to have a [assembly descriptor which describes](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html) what should be packaged into the archive like this:

```xml
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">

  <id>dist-assembly</id>

  <formats>
      <format>tar</format>
  </formats>

  <!--
     ! The following will include the base directory incl. version
     ! into the resulting tar.
     ! The default value is: true.
     ! <includeBaseDirectory>true</includeBaseDirectory>
  -->

  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>folder</directory>
      <outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

To control which folders are inside the archive you can use `outputDirectory` for it. The `directory` control which folder should be packaged into the archive.